# How to calculate the common volume/intersection between 2, 2D kde plots in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, shapely

I have 2 sets of datapoints:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})
```

For each one of these dataset I can produce the jointplot like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.jointplot(x=A["x"], y=A["y"], kind='kde')
sns.jointplot(x=B["x"], y=B["y"], kind='kde')
```

Is there a way to calculate the "common area" between these 2 joint plots ?

By common area, I mean, if you put one joint plot "inside" the other, what is the total area of intersection.  So if you imagine these 2 joint plots as mountains, and you put one mountain inside the other, how much does one fall inside the other ?

**EDIT**

To make my question more clear:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as st

def plot_2d_kde(df):
    # Extract x and y
    x = df['x']
    y = df['y']
    # Define the borders
    deltaX = (max(x) - min(x))/10
    deltaY = (max(y) - min(y))/10
    xmin = min(x) - deltaX
    xmax = max(x) + deltaX
    ymin = min(y) - deltaY
    ymax = max(y) + deltaY

    # Create meshgrid
    xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]

    # We will fit a gaussian kernel using the scipy’s gaussian_kde method
    positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    values = np.vstack([x, y])
    kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
    f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13, 7))
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, f, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='coolwarm', edgecolor='none')
    ax.set_xlabel('x')
    ax.set_ylabel('y')
    ax.set_zlabel('PDF')
    ax.set_title('Surface plot of Gaussian 2D KDE')
    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5) # add color bar indicating the PDF
    ax.view_init(60, 35)
```

I am interested in finding the interection/common volume (just the number) of these 2 kde plots:

```
plot_2d_kde(A)
plot_2d_kde(B)
```

Credits: The code for the kde plots is from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-example-of-2d-density-plots-in-python-83b83b934f67)

Comment: I don't think I understand. Your code only generates one plot - so "common area" between which two plots? Also, How exactly do you define common area?

Comment: @Roy2012 I edited my question, to also produce the 2nd joint plot. By common area, I mean, if you put one joint plot "inside" the other, what is the area of intersection.

Comment: common area: (1) do you mean the common area of the outermost shape (i.e., the one with the lightest color)? (2) Are you looking to plot the common area, or just calculate the area (e.g. - the common area is 7.2 sqm)?

Comment: 1 - I think I confused you with the term "area". I mean the common volume. So if you imagine these 2 joint plots as mountains, and you put one mountain inside the other, how much does one fall inside the other ?
2 - I am interested in just the number

Comment: @Roy2012 I added some extra information. I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code compares calculating the volume of the intersection either via scipy's `dblquad` or via taking the average value over a grid.

Remarks:

- For the 2D case (and with only 100 sample points), it seems the delta's need to be quite larger than 10%. The code below uses 25%. With a delta of 10%, the calculated values for `f1` and `f2` are about `0.90`, while in theory they should be `1.0`. With a delta of 25%, these values are around `0.994`.
- To approximate the volume the simple way, the average needs to be multiplied by the area (here `(xmax - xmin)*(ymax - ymin)`). Also, the more grid points are considered, the better the approximation. The code below uses 1000x1000 grid points.
- Scipy has some special functions to calculate the integral, such as `scipy.integrate.dblquad`. This is much slower than the 'simple' method, but a bit more precise. The default precision didn't work, so the code below reduces that precision considerably. (`dblquad` outputs two numbers: the approximate integral and an indication of the error. To only get the integral, `dblquad()[0]` is used in the code.)
- The same approach can be used for more dimensions. For the 'simple' method, create a more dimensional grid (`xx, yy, zz = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j, zmin:zmax:100j]`). Note that a subdivision by 1000 in each dimension would create a grid that's too large to work with.
- When using `scipy.integrate`, `dblquad` needs to be replaced by `tplquad` for 3 dimensions or `nquad` for N dimensions. This probably will also be rather slow, so the accuracy needs to be reduced further.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100), 'y':np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100), 'y':np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)})

# Extract x and y
x1 = df1['x']
y1 = df1['y']
x2 = df2['x']
y2 = df2['y']
# Define the borders
deltaX = (np.max([x1, x2]) - np.min([x1, x2])) / 4
deltaY = (np.max([y1, y2]) - np.min([y1, y2])) / 4
xmin = np.min([x1, x2]) - deltaX
xmax = np.max([x1, x2]) + deltaX
ymin = np.min([y1, y2]) - deltaY
ymax = np.max([y1, y2]) + deltaY

# fit a gaussian kernel using scipy’s gaussian_kde method
kernel1 = st.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x1, y1]))
kernel2 = st.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x2, y2]))

print('volumes via scipy`s dblquad (volume):')
print('  volume_f1 =', dblquad(lambda y, x: kernel1((x, y)), xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, epsabs=1e-4, epsrel=1e-4)[0])
print('  volume_f2 =', dblquad(lambda y, x: kernel2((x, y)), xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, epsabs=1e-4, epsrel=1e-4)[0])
print('  volume_intersection =',
    dblquad(lambda y, x: np.minimum(kernel1((x, y)), kernel2((x, y))), xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, epsabs=1e-4, epsrel=1e-4)[0])
```

Alternatively, one can calculate the mean value over a grid of points, and multiply the result by the area of the grid. Note that `np.mgrid` is much faster than creating a list via itertools.

```py
# Create meshgrid
xx, yy = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1000j, ymin:ymax:1000j]
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
f1 = np.reshape(kernel1(positions).T, xx.shape)
f2 = np.reshape(kernel2(positions).T, xx.shape)
intersection = np.minimum(f1, f2)
print('volumes via the mean value multiplied by the area:')
print('  volume_f1 =', np.sum(f1) / f1.size * ((xmax - xmin)*(ymax - ymin)))
print('  volume_f2 =', np.sum(f2) / f2.size * ((xmax - xmin)*(ymax - ymin)))
print('  volume_intersection =', np.sum(intersection) / intersection.size * ((xmax - xmin)*(ymax - ymin)))
```

Example output:

```
volumes via scipy`s dblquad (volume):
  volume_f1 = 0.9946974276169385
  volume_f2 = 0.9928998852123891
  volume_intersection = 0.9046421634401607
volumes via the mean value multiplied by the area:
  volume_f1 = 0.9927873844924111
  volume_f2 = 0.9910132867915901
  volume_intersection = 0.9028999384136771
```

Comment: Actually you are right. I accepted the other one because it seemed a bit more intuitive code wise, but you are correct, that it deviates quite a bit from the true answer. Would you say that it is easy to generalise your solution to n-dimensions ?

Comment: Well, for n-dimensions there is `nquad` to calculate the integral. Or you can just create an n-dimensional grid with `np.mesh`. Both approaches will get slow and have lower accuracy, But you should absolutely extend the domain by some delta, and you should absolutely multiply by the n-dimensional area of the domain. Also, take into account that a kde is just a smooth and approximate guess of the probability density function.

Comment: for `n=4` dimensions I am using `nquad(lambda z, w, y, x: np.minimum(kernel1((x, y, z, w)), kernel2((x, y, z, w))), [[xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax], [zmin, zmax], [wmin, wmax]])[0]` where the `4` dimensions in this case are `x,y,z,w`. I have two questions.

1) why is it `lambda w, z, y, x: kernel(x,y,z,w)` and not `lambda x,y,z,w: kernel(x,y,z,w)`
2) why isnt it needed to multiply by the area here ?

Comment: 1) The order is like that because the integral is calculated from the inside to the outside. It is just a convention used by scipy.  2) When calculating the integral via nquad or dblquad, the function itself already takes the "area" into account. When calculating just the average, you'll need to multiply the n-dimensional area to approximate the integral. Note that both methods are approximations. Speed and accuracy can differ.

Comment: I assume the speed goes higher where the accuracy goes lower, right ?

Comment: Can it be that the `volume_f1` is a bit larger than `1` but the `volume_f2` is quite smaller than `1` when using the 'simple' way ?

Comment: Both can be due to rounding errors, depending on the number of grid points. Anyway, with 3D or 4D it is hard to get a good accuracy. A too small value might be an indication that the domain of the grid should be larger. You can also experiment and just change the number of divisions with just 1 or 2 and see how that influences the result.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for. I'm basically calculating the space (integration) of the intersection (overlay) of the two KDE distributions.

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'x':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)], 'y':[random.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(0,100)]})

# KDE fro both A and B 
kde_a = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde([A.x, A.y])
kde_b = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde([B.x, B.y])

min_x = min(A.x.min(), B.x.min())
min_y = min(A.y.min(), B.y.min())
max_x = max(A.x.max(), B.x.max())
max_y = max(A.y.max(), B.y.max())

print(f"x is from {min_x} to {max_x}")
print(f"y is from {min_y} to {max_y}")
x = [a[0] for a in itertools.product(np.arange(min_x, max_x, 0.01), np.arange(min_y, max_y, 0.01))]
y = [a[1] for a in itertools.product(np.arange(min_x, max_x, 0.01), np.arange(min_y, max_y, 0.01))]

# sample across 100x100 points. 
a_dist = kde_a([x, y])
b_dist = kde_b([x, y])


print(a_dist.sum() / len(x))   # intergral of A
print(b_dist.sum() / len(x))   # intergral of B
print(np.minimum(a_dist, b_dist).sum() / len(x)) # intergral of the intersection between A and B
```

Comment: can this be generalised for more dimensions ?  if you use for instance `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde([A.x, A.y, A.z])`

Comment: Some remarks: the kde uses a larger area than the input samples, so `x = [a[0] for a in itertools.product(np.arange(0, 1, 0.01), np.arange(0, 1, 0.01))]` should use a larger range (that's why the integral of A is so far from the theoretical value of 1).  Also, the approximated integral should use the mean values multiplied by the area of the domain; here the domain is an area of 1x1, but in general that is seldom the case.  About generalizing to higher dimensions, the same approach could be used, but the accuracy will diminish quite a lot.

Comment: As to the same approach question for higher dimension - yes, it can be used. Just do kde_a = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde([A.x, A.y, A.z]).

Comment: Per @JohanC's (correct) comment, I'm now integrating from min_x/y to max_x/y, rather than from 0 to 1. Updated the solution a bit.

Comment: @quant - if this answers your question, do you mind accepting it for future generations?

Comment: @Roy2012 as in the question's code, you need to integrate from `min(x)-deltaX` to  `max(x)+deltaX`. The kde has a larger domain than the initial data. Also, you still need to multiply the endresult by the area of the two ranges.

Comment: @JohanC I understand why you need to increase the domain, but I do not understand why is the multiplication needed

Comment: @quant If you double the domain, you get many more near-zero values, so the average value gets lower. You compensate this by multiplying with the area of the domain.